# how to run eclipse on linux ubuntu for c programming?

Tags: c, linux, eclipse, ubuntu, ide

I'm new to Linux and beginner at c programming. I'm trying to install eclipse on Linux Ubuntu. I have installed openjdk-16-jdk and downloaded eclipse-cpp-kepler-SR2-linux-gtk-x86_64. When i try to open eclipse by double clicking on eclipse icon i get this message in the image

[image]

how can i get eclipse to run on Ubuntu ?

Comment: Eclipse Kepler is 9 years and 20 releases old, use the current Eclipse 2022-03 from https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

Comment: this is the last version on eclipse.org for c plug-in

Comment: No. Eclipse CDT is still available in the current Eclipse 2022-03

Answer (score 0):

Try to start Eclipse from the console:

home/eclipsePath/eclipse -clean

Comment: failed to launch with the same error and their was this message on the terminal "Failed to load module canberra-gtk-module "